# Applied CPLEX in YALMIP, Error 1001: Out of memory

Tags: cplex

YALMIP: Unknown problem in solver (Turn on 'debug' in sdpsettings) (Error using cplexmilp (line 328) `CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory.` )
I applied cplex solver in yalmip, but the model cannot be solved. I think the default memory settings lead to this error. The cplex settings code cannot be used in yalmip.

> cplex.setParam(IloCplex::WorkDir ,"c:/cplex/");
>           cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NodeFileInd ,2);
>    So how can I set the memory correctly. Thank you.

```
This is error information
There may be further error information in the clone logs.
Flow cuts applied:  116
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  299
Lift and project cuts applied:  75
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  60
Warning: MIP starts not constructed because of out-of-memory status.

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    5.02 sec. (945.62 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 4 threads:
  Real time             =  957.66 sec. (874133.10 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =   36.04 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.05 sec.
                      ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =  962.67 sec. (875078.72 ticks)

result = 

yalmiptime: NaN
solvertime: NaN
      info: [1x128 char]
   problem: 9
```

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. You're better off posting this at the YALMIP Google groups forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer does not have enough RAM to run your problem.

There are some tricks that you can do

- Set the MIPEmphasis parameter to 1. This will makes CPLEX emphasizes the search for feasible solutions, which can result in smaller B&B tree sizes.
- Set the NodeFileInt parameter to 3. It will force your B&B tree to be stored into the HD in a compressed file. However, this will greatly slow down the solver speed.
- Use the WorkMem parameter. Set it at a soft limit that can be handled by your RAM. After exceeding this limit, CPLEX will look at other memory strategies use by itself.
- Use CPLEX with only one thread. Therefore, none variable or state will be copied from one thread to another.

If none of these strategies work, then there is nothing we can do. You need to readjust your model or change to a PC with a greater amount of RAM.